# Getting a page curl effect with Unity / Flutter, doable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, flutter, flutter-animation, page-curl

I've got an application built in flutter where we have a page transition that currently just sticks to pretty out of the box stack/slide.

We're trying to create a page curl effect similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1znh05-iXY on the transition but not having much luck faking it with 2D animation/clip-path coupled with the gesture controlling the path similarly to the video being extremely difficult, almost impossible

Until we have some sort of 3D support within Flutter - the only way to do it that I can think of is using Unity3D via https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_unity_widget
But I don't know how this will work when we need it for every page?

**OR**

Going the other way and importing our Flutter app as a library in Unity to render every page within Unity.

Could I please gets some thoughts on whether either approach will work and any advice on a potential path forward?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

see this plugin, it's close to what you need you can take inspiration :)

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flip_card

Comment: Thanks for this, however, we've explored using "fake" transforms to get a flip effect. What we're looking for is similar to the curl effect above (check youtube link) where we want to have a 3D gesture controlled corner to a page. 
The flip page effect looks ok, but it quite obviously a mock of the animation that other engines can manage.